# Why is there another bus voltage rather than a supply voltage in current sense amplifier?

Tags: amplifier

For the [INA190](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina190.pdf) current sense amplifier, why are we given a bus voltage different from the supply voltage which ranges from-0.2v to 40 volt?

- What is its significance?
- Why can't we just connect it to the supply voltage?
- What will happen if we take the bus voltage from different supply but same in magnitude as the supply voltage?

Comment: The voltage range of the **bus** voltage is wider than the range of the **supply** voltage. You can connect bus and supply together but then you're **limited** to the range of the supply voltage: 1.7 V to 5.5 V. That is a much smaller range than -0.2 V to + 40 V.

Answer (score 2):

The part you're referring to is a high side current sense IC. The bus voltage is not a supply for the chip, but the power source for your load. The -0.2 to 40V range is the max and min of what the chip can handle. Anything in between those ranges will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the common-mode input range or **Vcm in the datasheet tables.**

When you exceed these limits of Vcm , it won't work for any Op Amp.

Shunts of 50 mV are useful for limiting power dissipation, but this can handle -200 mV for low side sensing as well as a high side sense while operating on a very low voltage.

This is an exceptionally good current-sense amplifier design for gain options and stability with the flexibility for bipolar currents and high or low side sensing.